# Series Convergence, Comparison theorem

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

$\sum_{n=2}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n(n-1)}$ The series must converge by the comparison theorem, but I'm struggling to find a convergent series I could compare it to.

Also, I wonder if integral test would work. 
Thanks for help!

Comment: To apply the integral test, you will need partial fractions.  You may find in that case that the series telescopes.  Alternatively, apply the limit comparison test against $\sum_n \frac{1}{n^2}$.

Comment: Isn't $ \frac{1}{n^2}$ less than $\frac{1}{n^2-n}$? I thought for comparison test we need a series  bigger then the one given, otherwise it doesn't work

Comment: **Limit** comparison.

Comment: To use comparison, note that $\frac{1}{n(n-1)} \leq \frac{1}{(n-1)^2}$ for $n>1$. Now why is the compared series convergent?

Comment: Does the name *Mengoli* ring some bell?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The integral test would work actually, so for that you want to see if the integral of $\int_2 ^\infty \frac{1}{n(n-1)} dn$ converges.
After some simple calculations, you should get the answer to be $ln(2)$ (I will leave this as an exercise for you to verify).
So since the integral converges, that means the series converges as well.

Comment: Both of those integrals diverge, though.  You should really combine your logs before evaluating, or you will fall into a dangerous "$\infty - \infty$" trap.

Comment: you can double check my work on Wolfram-Alpha (for the definite integral from 2 to infinity).

Comment: Exactly! that's the trick

Comment: Yeah, I get that, but you can't evaluate it as a sum of two divergent integrals, as you've displayed on the right-hand side.

Comment: So why ask the same question earlier before deleting?

Comment: not sure what you are talking about, but you have a point about the right-hand side, thanks!

Comment: LOL, okay.  I'm sure "Alina" will accept this as the best answer.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean @Randall, I think you might be in the wrong website though, this is a math site not Facebook.

Comment: @AliHeydari It does raise eyebrows that you asked [this same question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2456733/11619) 1 hour ago, then promptly deleted it. That link is viewable to 10k users. You see, nothing is permanently deleted here.

Answer (score 2):

For any $n >1$ $$(n-1)^2\le n(n-1) \le n^2$$ This implies

$$\sum_{n=2}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^2}<\sum_{n=2}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n(n-1)}<\sum_{n=2}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(n-1)^2}=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^2}$$ which finally makes

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^2}-1<\sum_{n=2}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n(n-1)}<\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^2}$$ and you know that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^2}=\frac {\pi^2}6$.

Answer (score 0):

This is another criterion, suppose we want to find a constant $c$ for which $$n(n-1) \ge cn^2, \ n=2,3,4, \cdots \tag{1}$$
Putting $n=2$ in (1), we obtain $$2 \ge 4c \tag{2}$$ Which implies that $$c \le 0.5 $$ We can choose $c=.5/2=0.25=\frac{1}{4}$. Hence, we have $$n(n-1)\ge \frac{n^2}{4}, \ n=2,3,4,\cdots \tag{3}$$ Transposing (3) we have $$\frac{1}{n(n-1)} \le \frac{4}{n^2}$$. Hence, you have got a series $\displaystyle \sum _{n=2} ^{\infty} \frac{4}{n^2}$, which converges by p-series test and combination theorem.